# Visual Studio Installation Error | Invalid Drive

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I know there's a ton of there install error posts but I have tried EVERYTHING from editing the registry to command line parameters, **I cannot get VS Community to install**.

A couple of years ago I tried to install VS Community to my old E:\ drive. That drive corrupted and/or stopped working, so I got a new drive (F:) and am currently trying to install it. I would be fine with installing it on my C:\ if necessary. I'm running `Windows 10 Pro 64x`.

I have also tried,

- Disabling all firewalls
- Re-downloading the installer
- Deleting the VS Folders from Local and Program Files

Literally everything I've seen here and on other forums. Oddly, *the installer does not create log files in Temp either*, so I'm at a loss of stuff to show.

And lastly, in apps, Visual Studio Community 2015 is listed with uninstall, however, when I go to uninstall, it also throws an error (no error code) saying:

> Fatal Error while installing.

And the exact install error:

> Invalid Drive

There's no error code but there is a grayed out box containing the drive path E:\

Honestly, I'm about ready to explode, I've been trying to install this nonsense for the last year. I wish installers were still the simple Windows Installer Wizard style, but of course developers have to come around and mess that up. Ironic though, the purpose of having this software is to make a app...let alone deal with one.

Comment: The installer is detecting that it is already installed (according to the MSI database). You'll need to clean up that database before you can install to another location.

Comment: So you mean an internal db? Sorry...idk

Comment: Windows keeps track of all MSIs run, the options (including the internal options that are never exposed to the user) selected, and which modules they install in an internal database. This is used, amongst other things to populate Programs and Features and to avoid a shared component being uninstalled until all components depending on it are uninstalled.

Comment: so...how does one edit this to "clean it up"?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the VS installation location defaults to the old invalid drive E:. This is because once a set of shared components is installed, we install all the other components to the same directory structure. When you have multiple editions installed, this saves disk space since shared files occupy the same location on disk – not to mention results in faster install times since Windows Installer doesn’t copy the same bits again.

[Heath Stewart has instructions on how to find the products that also installed these shared components and remove them](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/14/how-to-install-visual-studio-to-another-directory-when-a-pre-release-is-installed/); after that you should be able to modify VS installation location.

1. Download and install http://psmsi.codeplex.com. These are general-purpose PowerShell cmdlets I created for all sorts of development and troubleshooting operations for Windows Installer-based installs. You do not need to elevate to install them, though if you pre-elevate you can install them per-machine (by default they are per-user).
2. Open an elevated PowerShell command prompt and run the following to discover which products have installed the key shared component:

   ```
   get-msicomponentinfo '{777CBCAC-12AB-4A57-A753-4A7D23B484D3}' |
   get-msiproductinfo
   ```
3. If you’re fine with uninstalling all the listed products (especially given that you’re probably going to install RTM next), run the following:

   ```
   get-msicomponentinfo '{777CBCAC-12AB-4A57-A753-4A7D23B484D3}' | 
   get-msiproductinfo | uninstall-msiproduct -properties IGNOREDEPENDENCIES=ALL
   ```

Comment: I downloaded it, but can't open it...I don't see and .exe or .bat files I can run from command line.

Comment: Hi Jacob, after downloaded it you should find the 'psmsi.msi' and double-click it to install. After that, go to Start--All apps(Windows 10) and scroll down and find the Windows PowerShell folder and expand it, then right-click the first 'Windows PowerShell' cmd and run as administrator.

Comment: The .sin file doesn't work. I ended up downloading VS2013.

Comment: What's the .sin file stands for?

Comment: you said to run psmsi.msi, but there's only .sin?

Comment: I opened the website: http://psmsi.codeplex.com/, then I found there is an 'download' button at the right side of the current page, click it, it popups a little windows "Do you want to run or save psmi.msi (884K) form download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com?" at the button of the page, like this screenshot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKdXt80s2oy9iRmIE.

Comment: The msdn article is useless, Just now tried to follow that article, but I can't even run the "get-msicomponentinfo" command with the psmsi installed

Comment: @User2012384, you can access http://psmsi.codeplex.com/ or https://github.com/heaths/psmsi and it works fine on my local.

Comment: perfect thanks! for those ones who can't get psmi working on windows 10 run this first on an elevated power shell; Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have found a fix already. But I had run into this exact same issue. And the way I fixed was by following these steps.

1. Search "Manage disks and volumes" in your search bar and click on the option that comes up.
2. Choose either an unused drive, a junk drive that you are able to clear up, or create a partition in a drive that has extra space.
3. Label or re-label that drive/partition to whatever Visual Studio is wanting. (In your case it would be {E}.
4. Make sure to add the folders it thinks it needs to reach into the drive (for me it was called G:\VisualStudio\Components.

Now you should be able to download it again because it thinks all of the original file locations are present. And with it downloaded you should hopefully be able to manage/modify it however you want.